# How to use stopPropagation() using Javascript in a function with parameters

Tags: javascript

I have this function that takes parameters, I do not get how to stop the bubbling phase of the event when my function has parameters. I have tried the following code and none of them work.

```
function paraHandler(msg, e) {
    alert(msg);
    e.stopPropagation();
}

function paraHandler(msg) {
    alert(msg);
    msg.stopPropagation();
}

function paraHandler(msg) {
    alert(msg);
    this.stopPropagation();
}

var para = document.getElementById('closer');
para.addEventListener('click', function () {
    paraHandler('hello');
}, false);
window.addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert('window clicked');
}, false);
```

I get this error message: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.
The event shouldn't bubble up and alert 'window clicked' after para has been clicked.

Comment: have you tried `para.addEventListener('click', function(e){paraHandler('hello',e);}, false);`

Comment: no, let me try that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pass the event from the callback to the handler

```
para.addEventListener('click', function(event){
     paraHandler('hello',event);}
,false);
```